# How to change the format of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is one data frame with four columns (model, lot, part, qty)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'model':['AB','AB','AB','AB','AB','AB','AB','AB','AB','AB','AB','AB','AB','C','C','C'],
       'lot':['a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','c'],
       'part':['aa','ab','ac','ad','ae','af','ba','bb','bc','bd','be','bf','bg','ca','cb','cc'],
       'qty':[1,2,1,3,1,5, 2,3,4,5,3,2,1,2,3,3]})

    model lot part  qty
0     AB   a   aa    1
1     AB   a   ab    2
2     AB   a   ac    1
3     AB   a   ad    3
4     AB   a   ae    1
5     AB   a   af    5
6     AB   b   ba    2
7     AB   b   bb    3
8     AB   b   bc    4
9     AB   b   bd    5
10    AB   b   be    3
11    AB   b   bf    2
12    AB   b   bg    1
13     C   c   ca    2
14     C   c   cb    3
15     C   c   cc    3
```

I would like to ***change the format of the data frame as follows.***

[image]

I know that this will eliminate the meaning of the column. But I will only use it for ***only display or printer purposes***.

It doesn't have to be the same. I just need to make it ***as close as possible***

Comment: You can probably do this with some kind of pivot operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
df.groupby(['model', 'lot'], as_index=False).agg(lambda x: list(x))
```

result:

```py
   model    lot    part                            qty
0  AB       a      [aa, ab, ac, ad, ae, af]        [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 5]
1  AB       b      [ba, bb, bc, bd, be, bf, bg]    [2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1]
2  C        c      [ca, cb, cc]                    [2, 3, 3]
```